# Getting checkMarx Path Traversal issue during the code scan with checkMarx tool

Tags: .net, vb.net, checkmarx

Getting **checkMarx Path Traversal issue while executing HttpWebRequest**,

*Error message from checkmarx:*
Gets dynamic data from the headers element. This element’s value then flows through the code and is eventually used in a file path for local disk access.

The only input I passed in the header is token to access the API. Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Below is the code, I'm getting the token from the cookie and pass it along with the httpRequest.

```
Dim responseString As String = ExecuteURL("www.mysite.com\action")

Private Function ExecuteURL(ByVal url As String) As String

        Dim basicRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        basicRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        basicRequest.Method = "GET"

        Dim cookie As HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("token")
        If Not cookie Is Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value) Then
            basicRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "service" + cookie.Value)
        End If
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Try
            response = CType(basicRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            If Not response Is Nothing Then
                Using streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                    Return streamReader.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End If
        Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
            Using streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                Return streamReader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Try

        Return String.Empty
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the vulnerability which is mentioned in owasp as well. For better understanding and ways to resolve, I would suggest give a read on this - https://blog.mindedsecurity.com/2018/10/how-to-prevent-path-traversal-in-net.html